# How to change widget background using RemoteViews?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

And now I want to change this background to "@drawable/your_bck" using RemoteViews. I tried something like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.yout_bck);
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget, bitmap);
```

But i then it shows "Widget failed to load"

It must be as a background because i need to set a text on the center of image :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `setImageViewBitmap` on a `RelativeLayout`. A `RelativeLayout` is not an `ImageView`. You could put an `ImageView` in there instead that fills the `RelativeLayout` and call it on that.

Comment: I see, but I need to put some Text on the center of this image. I want to make something like battery widget. :)

Comment: OK, so put a TextView centered on top of the ImageView.

Comment: Oh my God, it works. I was trying to do that earlier but i was thinking it isn't possible to do in this way. Thank you so much :) Ohh this terrible GUI UI editor :/

Comment: Yeah, don't count on the GUI editor. Just edit the XML. If this was enough, you can accept it as the answer (hit the check mark on the left of my answer).

Comment: Done. I guess now I can update this imageview using code which i wrote up, yup?